# Xamarin forms: Image is not showing in perfect circle

Tags: xamarin.forms, circleimage

I already posted a question regarding this issue, never get any solution. So posting the same question with more details and findings.

For the circle images, I am using Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle nuget package in my project, which is working fine in android and windows but showing an oval shape in IOS, screenshot adding below.

[image]

Added ImageCircleRenderer.Init(); in AppDelegate.cs.

xmlns namespace added:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"  

  <controls:CircleImage 
          HorizontalOptions="Start"
          VerticalOptions="Start"
          Margin="0,0,0,-5"
          WidthRequest="50" 
          Aspect="AspectFill"
          BorderColor="#1C7DB4"
          BorderThickness="2"
           HeightRequest="50" />
```

Now I updated the Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle to 2.0.2 and the resulted image is adding below:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you are displaying the circles in a `ListView`, which has a fixed height of the cells per default. It seems as if your cells are simply not high enough to give the `CircleImage`s the space they need. You have two options to overcome this:

- Set the cells heigth to a fixed value that is high enough.

  - I don't know the exact value of the cells padding, so you'll have to experiment a bit. Maybe start off with something around 60

`<ListView RowHeight="60" ...>`

- Set `HasUnevenRows="true"`

  - I believe that this will fix the rows height automagically, but it comes at costs: There may be a negative impact on layouting your view.

`<ListView HasUnevenRows="true">`

Comment: Yes, I tried, 65 height is working fine, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @SreejithSree I could have, but I rather marked the other question as a duplicate, which will create a link to this question.

Comment: @SreejithSree At the end of the day we are developers and try to adhere to the DRY principle ;)